# How and when is `/sys/kernel/security/tpm0/binary_bios_measurements` exposed?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, uefi, secure-boot, tpm

Currently, I try to understand how a measured boot is working and what components log what in which pcr of a tpm2.

I have a test-setup with uefi-secure boot enabled and a tpm2 attached in a kvm virtualized machine.
I compiled my own kernel with tpm support etc. `tpm2_pcrread` gives reasonable output. Now I want to look inside the events of the tpm. But there is no `/sys/kernel/security/tpm0` and therefore no `binary_bios_measurement`.
If I live boot from the ubuntu 23.10 iso, the file is present and can be read by tpm2_eventlog. So i take the kernel from ubuntu and booted the system with it, but also here, there is no  `/sys/kernel/security/tpm0`.
No my guess is, that i miss kernel module that exposes this. Or systemd in ubuntu creates this path. I do not find any documentation about this.
I do not know how to find out where and who creates this path/file. Does someone know how to expose the  `binary_bios_measurement`?
PS. on my own linux I am using OpenRc and not systemd.

Comment: Did you also take the kernel *modules* from Ubuntu, not only the vmlinux? TPM access needs its own drivers which are often modular.

Comment: Yes, I also use the Ubuntu kernel modules; but created my own initramfs, that loads some of them. But I found already out, that it seems something to do with the bootloader, as strange as it sounds…

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the `securityfs` virtual filesystem mounted?

If `grep ^securityfs /proc/mounts` outputs nothing, you don't have it mounted. To mount it manually:

```
sudo mount -t securityfs none /sys/kernel/security
```

If you want to have it always mounted, add this line to your `/etc/fstab` file:

```
none  /sys/kernel/security  securityfs  defaults  0 0
```

Comment: Unfortently this seems not to be the issue. The securityfs is already present. Btw it is not empty: 

`localhost:~# ls /sys/kernel/security/` gives 

`apparmor   evm        ima        integrity  lockdown   lsm`


but the tpm0 dir is missing.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trail and error and reading kernel code I accidentally found the solution, but not really the reason.

I used GRUB 2.06. When I tried the GRUB version shipped with Ubuntu - which is 2.12 - suddenly the `tpm0` dir was present. So I compiled also GRUB by myself using this version and the missing dir is present.

I am a little bit surprised, since as I read GRUB supports measured boot since 2.06. And even if not, what has the bootloader to do with the fact that the kernel exposes this path?

**UPDATE**

Now I am event more surprised. I signed my GRUB with `sbsign` and installed my PK,KEK,db in the `efivars`. And suddenly the dir is missing again. If I clear the keys in the BIOS, the dir is present again... Mysterious.